# Locate bbc London location - Selenium Web Driver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Please can someone kindly advise how to write a function to capture the location "London" on bbc.co.uk website.
here are the steps.

1- navigate to www.bbc.co.uk

2- Ensure the pagetitle is BBC Homepage

3- ensure the location is London.

I would be very grateful of your help and thank you in advance.

Is there an easier way to locate the element on the page? What do I need to learn to become comfortable with this?

This is just for my learning purposes.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to locate the city from the weather widget on the right?

Comment: Yes, it is in the left hand side of the page and the weather info are on the right.

Comment: Add your code and html to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you would inspect the desired element using browser developer tools, you would see that it is located in the `div` with `weather_forecast` id. You can locate it, for example, using a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#weather_forecast h3")).getText();
```

Comment: <a class="location" href="/locator/default/desktop/en-GB?ptrt=%2F" title="Change your location">London</a>

Comment: That is the location I am trying validate.

Comment: @HK009 for this element, use `a.location` CSS selector.

Comment: Assert.assertTrue("Ensure location is London", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b-r[location]")).equals("London"));

Answer (score 0):

WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#h4clock a.location"));
        String getcity = city.getText();